# Run telegram bot in multiple clusters using pm2

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, pm2, node-telegram-bot-api

I'm currently running a telegram bot using the node-telegram-bot-api.
But now the project is getting bigger and bigger and more users are using my bot.
So I had some difficulties when I had to re-deploy my app while many people are still on access.
I tried to run multiple clusters using pm2 and then use pm2 reload to gracefully restart my app in zero downtime.

But then I got an error from telegram:

```
error: [polling_error] {"code":"ETELEGRAM","message":"ETELEGRAM: 409 Conflict: terminated by other getUpdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running"}
```

I think telegram doesn't provide multiple instances in the same server.
Is there any solutions for this kind of problem?

Answer (score 1):

Even if you could run script twice, users will get answers twice when they sends commands to bot.
you have two options two do:

- Upgrade Your resources (RAM/CPU/...)
- Handle incoming messages with your main script, make a API and do processes in API backend.